# Is is possible to add a second value when you use a Select for insert?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Archivos (Nombre, Descripcion)
    SELECT Nombre_Salida, Nombre_Salida 
    FROM dbo.Archivos_Temporales
    WHERE Nombre_Salida LIKE (@Id_Relacion_Articulo_Archivo + '%')
```

This works, however, there is possible to do something like this:

```
Insert in dbo.Archivo(
  "Nombre" which will come from the select, 
  "Nombre_Salida" from another select or hardcoded value)
```

?

Comment: Nothing prevents you to use a join, or table expressions in the `SELECT`. In fact it can be as complex as you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending that answer, to show that you can insert from

...a hard coded value

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Archivos (Nombre, Descripcion)
SELECT Nombre_Salida, 'foo' --> hardcoded
FROM dbo.Archivos_Temporales
WHERE ...
```

...two different tables

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Archivos (Nombre, Descripcion)
SELECT Archivos_Temporales1.col_1, Archivos_Temporales2.col_a
FROM dbo.Archivos_Temporales1, dbo.Archivos_Temporales2
WHERE...
```

...similarly, you can stack queries

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Archivos (Nombre, Descripcion)
SELECT Archivos_Temporales1.col_1, 'foo'
FROM dbo.Archivos_Temporales1
WHERE...
UNION
SELECT 'bar', Archivos_Temporales2.col_1
FROM dbo.Archivos_Temporales2
WHERE...
```

Work on getting the SELECT to produce the results that you need, then add the INSERT line

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a hardcoded value in the second colum, you can just pass the litteral string to your query, like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Archivos (Nombre, Descripcion)
SELECT Nombre_Salida, 'foo' --> hardcoded
FROM dbo.Archivos_Temporales
WHERE ...
```